# Extending backend lists object

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

how could I extend the list items which are displayed in backend?

I am trying to use this function:

```
listExtendRecords($records)
```

The thing is that I need to recreate the same object $records, but I want to add my custom data to it. For example my records is orders from JK Shop plugin. What I need is to take all the products from those orders and make each product as a different list item.

I could do these changes in this function and just return the $records, but how could I create a new object of items here? I tried using:

```
$new = new Production();
return $new;
```

But I get :

> Call to undefined method October\Rain\Database\QueryBuilder::currentPage()

How could I make a new working Object which could be returned to the backend list?

Comment: Are you coding a plugin? you wish to show products as a relation to an order? check out https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, from your question you want to show `related items` (**products of order**) `under the`order record` it self,

> it seems its not possible using extension or may be it become more hard/complex if we use that thing

instead we can use `small trick`

we will `override partial` for `list` for that particular list, to do so we can use its `config_list.yaml`

with that `order` list config add this additional option

```
....
toolbar:
buttons: list_toolbar
search:
    prompt: 'backend::lang.list.search_prompt'
recordUrl: 'hardiksatasiya/demotest/demo/update/:id'
// add customViewPath
customViewPath: $/hardiksatasiya/demotest/controllers/demo/list_override
```

now here we override 2 partials (i have copied them from `modules\backend\widgets\lists\partials`)

```
_list_body_rows.htm
_list_body_row.htm
```

i modify there content

> **_list_body_rows.htm**

```
<?php foreach ($records as $record): ?>
    <?= $this->makePartial('list_body_row', [
        'record' => $record, 
        'treeLevel' => $treeLevel, 
        'custom' => isset($custom) ? true : false]) 
?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

> **_list_body_row.htm**

```
<?php
    $expanded = $showTree ? $this->isTreeNodeExpanded($record) : null;
    $childRecords = $showTree ? $record->getChildren() : null;
    $treeLevelClass = $showTree ? 'list-tree-level-'.$treeLevel : '';
?>
<tr class="<?= $treeLevelClass ?> <?= $this->getRowClass($record) ?>">
    <!-- we are using that custom variable here we dont want to show check box for our products-->
    <?php if ($showCheckboxes && $custom == false): ?>
        <?= $this->makePartial('list_body_checkbox', ['record' => $record]) ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($showTree): ?>
        <?= $this->makePartial('list_body_tree', [
            'record' => $record,
            'expanded' => $expanded,
            'childCount' => $record->getChildCount()
        ]) ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <!-- we are using that custom variable here 
        and make our row seperatly as we need
        for all item/product record this partial executed so
        we code it for single row it will be repeated through all product items automatically-->
    <?php if($custom): ?>
        <td> <!-- checkbox column we make it blank--> </td>
        <!-- 
            colspan based on requirement 
            you can fully customize your td tags from here
        -->
        <td colspan="<?= count($columns) ?>"> <a href="/backend/products/edit/<?= $record->id ?>"> <?= $record->name ?> </a></td>

    <?php else: ?>

        <?php $index = $url = 0; foreach ($columns as $key => $column): ?>
            <?php $index++; ?>
            <td class="list-cell-index-<?= $index ?> list-cell-name-<?= $column->getName() ?> list-cell-type-<?= $column->type ?> <?= $column->clickable ? '' : 'nolink' ?> <?= $column->cssClass ?>">
                <?php if ($column->clickable && !$url && ($url = $this->getRecordUrl($record))): ?>
                    <a <?= $this->getRecordOnClick($record) ?> href="<?= $url ?>">
                        <?= $this->getColumnValue($record, $column) ?>
                    </a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= $this->getColumnValue($record, $column) ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </td>
        <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($showSetup): ?>
        <td class="list-setup">&nbsp;</td>
    <?php endif ?>
</tr>

<?php if ($showTree && $expanded): ?>
    <?= $this->makePartial('list_body_rows', ['records' => $childRecords, 'treeLevel' => $treeLevel+1]) ?>
<?php endif ?>

<!-- you can customise this condition basde on your order have items or not
i used simple relation condition here -->
<?php if ($record->relation): ?>

    <?php $childRecords = is_array($record->relation) ? $record->relation : [$record->relation]; ?>
    <?php
        // currently as $childRecords i used relation but you can create your own model array
        // and pass here it will be received in next iteration
        // notice we are passing $custom variable and we also override
        // _list_body_rows.htm and it will loop through all records and pass
        // $custom  variable and it will be true based on its existance
        // if we pass custom variable it will pass it also with true other wise
        // it will pass it false
    ?>

    <?= $this->makePartial('list_body_rows', ['records' => $childRecords, 'treeLevel' => $treeLevel+1, 'custom' => true]) ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

> **it will give you output like this**

[image]

i have also `added comments` in `new paritals` how to use them if you need mroe information please comment.

Comment: I solved this by creating a new controller, which gets each product as separate list item. But thank you very much for an informative post, I will definitely use this on other part of the project I am working on. Nice!